# Compare to the IDE for Java,do we still need Ant?

Tags: eclipse, ant

Not long before I had digged into Ant and use it doing simple practice(compile,unit test,package).Now my usual work is under Eclipse for java development,the usual work can all be simply done through Eclipse' function:in-time compiling、click button to deploy、various wizard..

So I am wondering under Eclipse do we have a need for Ant. 
And if it is, at which aspect should we use Ant along with Eclipse.

Answer (score 11):

Building applications is not about just building them in your IDE. You need to setup an automated build and deploy method that can be run for, say, continuous integration and deployment. The built package has to be deloyed to various environments and finally production. You cannot build them out of your own box. You cannot build it out of your IDE. You need separate build system. That is where build tools like ANT come in.

Also note that the capabilities of IDEs for doing build, deploy is limited and that is not their strength. It is, however, possible to make use of ANT and its build scripts and [run them out of eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-81_basics.htm). This way, you have a single set of scripts for both your local ( developer ) build and the main build process. With ANT being JAVA based, you can also suit your build tool to your needs by writing custom tasks etc.

Also, when you make use of something as standard as ANT for your build system, you can move to a different IDE like Intellij IDEA and still make use of the build system that you know.

Comment: I would like to add that ant is used mainly for building a source code in a custom structure (have lib folder of jars referanced, have documentation of the app, ...) and form a jar. In eclipse you can create a jar for your project. but you cant control the folders and other contents of the jar. In effect less flexibility.

Answer (score 4):

Do you need Ant if you can build through the IDE? Of course not! You can see that yourself.

Should you still have a IDE independent build with standard tools? Of course!

Note I didn't say *Ant*. There are a number of build tools such as Maven or Gradle that are made to build Java programs. However, there are reasons why you want an IDE independent build system:

- **You have a Continuous Integration Server**: You do have one. Right? If you don't get one. A Continuous Integration Server automatically builds your project (and runs every test) each time a change is committed to the version control system. It catches mistakes. It also provides an **OFFICIAL BUILD**. No more *It worked on my machine!* excuses. If the Continuous Integration Server can't build it and successfully run the tests, the software isn't good.
- **You have others who need to work with your project on a different computer in a different environment**: The problem with IDEs is that its specific to your system. Someone else checks out your project, and they may be using a different IDE. They maybe have a slightly different setup. An independent build scripting language like Ant guarantees that they can rebuild your project as intended.

If you share a project with someone else, you need an independent standard method way of being able to build that project and to know exactly what is required for that build to work. IDEs can hide that information.

Answer (score 2):

I am a benchmark tester using Ant everyday. Our environment has 7 test machines and 1 console machine. For each test run, the ant script updates the working copy, restarts the database, build the product and the Grinder with proper properties and deploy them to the machines, and starts them and the monitoring softwares. With the 1000-line-buildfile, I can just type in an "ant A B C D E"-like line in the terminal on the console machine. I don't think it's a good idea to do this in a IDE like eclipse or NetBeans or anything else.

Also, in my company's product, ant is widely used. We use ant to build sample data for the benchmark test; we use ant to update Tomcat which is going to be bundled with our product; we also use ant to build and run selenium tests.

What's more, when you want to release the source code, including the IDE project files is not a good idea because there are a lot of IDEs. And what if the user just want to get a fresh build from your latest code (if you don't provide nightly build)? Providing a set of ant (or other build tool) buildfiles is a good idea. With this, you can manage your classpath for the build.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest answer here wold be flexibility. The IDEs may came with pre-defined functionalities and may even allow you to choose some options using wizards. It is like generating html with Dreamweaver or such tools. It will never be as flexible as the pure thing. For example NetBeans uses Ant underneath.

Quoted from: [Netbeans: Build Tools](https://netbeans.org/features/java/build-tools.html)

> The default NetBeans IDE project system is built directly on top of
>   the Ant build system. All of the project commands, such as "Build
>   Project" and "Run File in Debugger", call targets in the project's Ant
>   script. You can therefore build and run your project outside the IDE
>   exactly as it is built and run inside the IDE.

Even after you use tools for that purpose you are most likely still to brush up. So, what I am saying is, what the IDEs do for you is only a subset of what you can do with the pure ant or maven( if you use it). For simple tasks such as compile and run, IDEs do pretty much a good job! But if you have a use case as complex as deploying on CI IDEs won't help you. You need the whole flexibility of your build tools.