# Using jdk with javac instead of ant

Tags: apache, ant, build

I wrote a sample app when trying out java.

calculator/Calc.java

```
package calculator;

public abstract class Calc {
    public static float Add(float f1, float f2) {
        return f1 + f2;
    }
    public static float Subtract(float f1, float f2) {
        return f1 - f2;
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
import calculator.Calc;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println("1+1=" + Calc.Add(1f, 1f));
        System.out.println("1-0.5=" + Calc.Subtract(1f, 0.5f));
    }
}
```

I managed to compile these classes using jdk into their class files.

Browsing on the web, I found a package called Ant which allows to compile files too. Compiling with Ant also gives me the java class files.

What I want to know is, whats the need for Ant when I can compile my classes directly using jdk without writing any configuration file. Is investing some time into Ant any good when I can build my code using jdk straight away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ant is a **build automation tool**. It can be used to not only compile classes but also run those classes, test those classes,generate javadocs. Mainly used for independent deployment and/or testing of an application.

> whats the need for Ant when I can compile my classes directly using
>   jdk without writing any configuration file.

[Check this out.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10764576/why-do-we-need-maven-or-ant-if-we-already-have-eclipse)

> Is investing some time into Ant any good when I can build my code
>   using jdk straight away?

Depends on what you want to do with our code. Look up Maven and Gradle as well. 
[Gradle](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/why-build-your-java-projects-with-gradle/240168608) is the newest among them and arguably better as well.

Comment: I was able to compile classes, archive them and even package them using ant. Its useful with a few lines of configuration. I think its something I was looking for. Thanks for your reply.